# Entity Framework, Custom Control, and No connection string named x, Still Runs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I recently rewrote a large program that my company uses to conduct business. I changed to Entity Framework early on. For the most part it has been working quite well.

One issue that has annoyed me for quite some time and now I have time to look into is, a custom control that pulls a question from the database causes a strange error.

When the custom control used SQL it would actually show the question on form display in the designer. At first this was pretty cool and I liked it. After switching it to use Entity Framework 6, when I load the form in the designer I get the error

> No connection string named 'wotcDB' could be found in the application
>   config file.

It's totally in the app.config file. In fact the program has no problem compiling and running without issue. For the longest time I would just push Ignore and go to work on the form. The question of course no longer shows up in the designer.

The User Control is part of the application. The app.config file is there, and the program both runs and deploys fine. What's causing this?

Here is my app.config, ####### is sensitive data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="webDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.webDB.csdl|res://*/Data.webDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.webDB.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;user id=#######;password=#######;server=#######;database=#######;persistsecurityinfo=True&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="wotcDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.wotcDB.csdl|res://*/Data.wotcDB.ssdl|res://*/Data.wotcDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=#######;initial catalog=#######;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data></configuration>
```

Comment: Is the data access code built into the control? Is the control class declared in the same project as the form it's on?

Comment: It is built into the control. The control class is in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deal with the issue, since only I see it. I've found an answer at
[This Stack Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774689/how-to-have-code-in-the-constructor-that-will-not-be-executed-at-design-time-by)
I put

```
    If (System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.UsageMode = System.ComponentModel.LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) Then
        Load_Question()
    End If
```

in the custom control load. I don't see the question during design time, which is fine for me. My other option was to put the connection string into the EF class, which is difficult to keep up since I'm using EF-Design and not code first.